# When musescore is open (using jack), how to videos from YouTube either are paused or have no sound

Tags: 15.10, youtube, jack, musescore

When using musescore, I'm trying to follow how-to videos found on YouTube. However, I find that when musescore is open, videos are paused or there is no sound. As soon as I turn off musescore, video playback resumes.

Am I falling victim mechanisms designed to prevent digital copying? I'm not trying to steal anything or download YT videos. I'm trying to follow along to how-to videos to better learn piece of software.

**Question:** How can I follow along to how to videos online on the same machine? That is, how can I follow along to these videos and have Musescore open at the same time? Are browsers "protecting" content from being recorded? Should I switch Musescore to ALSA or PULSE?

*Note:* I'm ***NOT*** looking to circumvent DRM. I'm just want to follow along a how-to video.

[image]

Comment: Yes, switch to ALSA or PULSE, and see if either one works. I don't know much about JACK, but I wonder if it's like ASIO4ALL, in that it prevents other applications from accessing the audio device. I have MuseScore set to ALSA, and I could play a song in Parole Media Player, while playing a MIDI file in the former.

Comment: @theodorn I imagine you should put this as an answer.  I'll give this a shot. Upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP suggested I put my comment as an answer. Which I was reluctant to do, but it's probably better for archiving purposes. At least if no other answer comes along.

I suggest switching to ALSA first, and if it doesn't work, then PULSE. JACK might be locking access to the audio device, or it could be a routing path issue.